# How to remove first two parts in a URL?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove parts in a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946280/how-to-remove-parts-in-a-url)

I want to know how to remove first two parts of a URL in php?

I have a url called - `http://localhost/photo/user-content/uploads/wall/o/74/ruveena.jpg`

It means i want to remove - `http://localhost/photo/`

and I want make this URL to

```
user-content/uploads/wall/o/74/ruveena.jpg
```

I searched evrywhere but there only how to remove query part or host n those stuff i want to remove just only the first two parts of this url.

Comment: I have a feeling of a déjà vu!

Comment: You just posted the exact same question which was closed because you *didn't show anything you've tried*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$url = parse_url('http://localhost/photo/user-content/uploads/wall/o/74/ruveena.jpg', PHP_URL_PATH);
$url = trim($url, '/');
$new_path = substr($url, strpos($url, '/') + 1);
```